# Get variables from other class from button click

Tags: c#, winforms, class, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Fairly new to C# and while working through some tutorials I've hit a problem.

How would I pass the variable generated from one class back to the main form so that I can display it on a button click?

This code simulates a patient's heart rate:

```
class patientSim
{
    int hr = new int();

    public static genStats()
        {
            Random hr_ = new Random();
            int hr = hr_.Next(40, 131);
        }
}
```

This code should display the heart rate, *hr*, on button click.

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    public static void simBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        patientSim.genStats();
        MessageBox.Show = hr;
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's very simple but I can quite get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method needs a return value:

```
public static int genStats()
    {
        Random hr_ = new Random();
        int hr = hr_.Next(40, 131);
        return hr;
    }
```

then use that:

```
public static void simBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int hr = patientSim.genStats();
    MessageBox.Show(hr);
}
```

remember you have to declare a return value on your methods.  If you don't want to return anything, you'd use `void`

Answer (score 1):

The class `patientsSim` (which by convention should be written `PatientSim` has `hr` defined as a private field.  You need to modify that class in order to access it.  One possible modification would be to add a getter to patientSim that returns the value of `hr`:

```
public int Hr { get { return hr; } }
```

Then in your form

```
    patientSim.genStats();
    MessageBox.Show("HR: " + patientSim.Hr);
```

You have a few additional problems though:

```
int hr = hr_.Next(40, 131);
```

hides the class-level variable `hr`.  So change that to

```
hr = hr_.Next(40, 131);
```

Then, you have a mismatch between instance and statically scoped parts of your class.  You can change the class level `hr` to be static, along with the proposed getter, or change the event handler to be non-static.